# SpecFlow.ExternalData is causing dotnet build to fail - cannot deploy to Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, bdd, specflow

I have a problem with deploying the project to Azure DevOps because of the ExternalData.
On my local machine, VS can build the project and tests work fine.

But, when I try to build the project with the command 'dotnet build' as it does on AzureDevops, it fails.

Error that I get:

> Generation error: Message: Unable to load Excel file from pathToProject\Features\Something.xlsx': Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelDataReader, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The same happens with CSV file, only it says CSVHelper instead of ExcelDataReader.
I tried to install ExcelDataReader and nothing changed.
I tried to manually copy ExcelDataReader.dll to my bin folder and then add it's dependency and still nothing changed.

Can someone please help?
This is a vital part of our tests, to be able to use Excel or CSV files for test data.

EDIT:

Steps to reproduce:

There is a feature file that has a data source tag for the excel file:

```
@DataSource:ExcelFileName.xlsx
Scenario Outline: Get something
    Given I request a something with id "<Id>"
    Then the name of a something should be "<Name>"
```

If I build this locally on my machine in Visual Studio, it works and also test work. (If I do rebuild, or build).

If I enter the package manager console and do a command 'dotnet build' I get the error from above.
This is the same command that is executed on AzureDevops.

Also, the excel file has:
Build action: Content
Copy to output directory: Copy always

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Can you [edit] your question to include a [repro]?

Comment: yes I can, but there is only one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed on SpecFlow side in the new version 3.9.52.